# Where may I receive some opinions about site designs?

Tags: design

I´m working on a new design for my website. It´s almost finished.
I would like some other people to look at the new design comparing it to the old one and just tell me if they like it more or less, or what opinions do they have about it.

Where could I do that? I have an account at [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/Rosamunda_ar) for some time now, but I´ve just recently added me as a prospect there, so, until I get "selected" I can´t post anything.

Is there any other places where you think I could receive some opinions from other fellows? After reading the FAQ, I understand that I can´t do that here.

Thanks!

Rosamunda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many other design communities that you can consider using, these are:

1. [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/)
2. [Red Bubble](http://www.redbubble.com/)
3. [Visual.ly](http://visual.ly/)
4. [Cargo](http://cargocollective.com/)
5. [Creattica](http://creattica.com/)
6. [Pikto Chart](http://piktochart.com/)
7. [Image Spark](http://www.imgspark.com/)
8. [Design Bump](http://www.designbump.com)
9. [UX User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

I've made this as a Community Wiki so feel free to contribute to the list.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may find some good help at [User Experience.](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's only suitable on UX.SE if it's an actual question, not just a 'please critique my site' question. All stack exchange sites are Question and Answer sites to provide benefit to other people searching for answer to questions. In it's present form it's likely to be closed as being 'too localised' over on UX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pay for it you may look out for services like:

- http://www.usertesting.com/
- http://www.trymyui.com/
- https://www.ui-check.com/

(I can't tell about the quality, just bookmarked them).

Also give http://www.behance.net/ a try.

If you have a "social network", followers, influencers, you may kindly ask for their feedback and share the designs.